# Specifying .getLastRow in a function for a specific column

Tags: javascript

Im new to Google Sheets Scripts and I was trying to create a code to add Time to cell in an specific column using a button. I got the code down as shown below but I want the .getLastRow function to only apply to one especific column, not to find the very last row in the entire doc.

Any help?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

function PreOpIN() {
    ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow() + 1,9).setValue(new Date())
}
```

Comment: Is there a `getLastColumn`?

Comment: Yes, but not sure how it is relevant here. The column I want is not the last column either.